# Split screen concept for tablet in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application for tablet which has Split screen functionality,as we see an Gmail Application. My Left layout is fixed and my right one will change as per the buttons clicked on it.

```
 I googled a lot for the solution,I found that we need to use Fragments for performing these.
```

Can anyone help me in solving these things.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could have explored [d.android.com](http://developer.android.com/) but now I would suggest you to refer it whenever you are facing problems/issues or looking for basic help.

Now, As you want to provide split functionality kind of UI in Android, check: [Building a Flexible UI](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) and I would suggest you to learn and explore [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you got that right. `Fragments` is the solution here. Using Fragments is easy and it's lifecycle is similar to that of an `Activity`. First get an overview of what a Fragment is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Go over some of the tutorials about the use of Fragments : [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html) and [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/get-started-with-android-fragments/1050).

Answer (score 0):

this is a working example of what you want to achieve, good luck!
https://github.com/Jachu5/Android-UIprojects/tree/master/FragmentSplitedScreen